# Remove and replace 5.4 liter motor on 2007 F 150

Tags: ford, f-150, book-hours

Wondered if any one can give an idea of how many hours, by flat rate manual , are allowed for removal and replacement of complete engine assy?

Comment: Book time or time by skilled mech on a bonus scheme or time by a novice reading each step in the manual?

Comment: @SolarMike - Book time, as in, what does a reputable shop who charges by the book? Not how long does it take to do ... this is the *whole* purpose behind *book hours*, is it not? To have a general idea of how long the industry says it will take and can therefore charge the customer? I'm sure you have access to this type of information ... or am I making a bad assumption?

Comment: Book time is that specified by the manufacturer as the benchmark time for qualified and model-trained mechanics / technicians with access to all the manufacturer supplied special tools and equipment. Amazingly I don't have that manual as supplied by Ford ... Do you?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 after a google search - the most common indication was $1000 for the work but no mention of time...

Comment: @SolarMike - Don't need something provided by Ford. Most reputable shops (even those which aren't run by Ford) have such manuals (or can look it up online through subscription services). I thought with your connections you'd have it available to you. Obviously I was wrong. No worries. I'm sure someone will have it available.

Comment: Can you be more specific? R&R times vary from 12-22 hours (22 doesn't include manifolds etc...) depending on how disassembled the engine is and whether it's RWD or 4WD. A Safe estimate would probably be in the 28-30 hour area including tune parts fluids etc... Removal Installation and Overhauling shows as 36 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Book time is 14.8 hours. This includes transferring all fuel and electrical units.
It does not include transferring of optional equipment. Source is Repair-Source

Answer (score 0):

I pulled a 5.4 out of a 2007 F150 2WD and put a new remanned in the truck in under 10 hours. So saying anywhere close to 30 hours is out of this world rediculous. I didn't have a vehicle lift or any of that.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Remember, flat rate (or book rate) is the hours the repair manual states it should take to get the job done. This has nothing to do with how fast the mechanic can actually do the work. A good mechanic can do it faster, while a more meticulous one might do it slower. Book hours were put in place a long time ago so the customer wouldn't get screwed. It levels the playing field between the shop and the customer.